# Where can I get Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement DLL?

Tags: dll, tridion

I want to access "Fields" property for accessing fields of a schema in core services in SDL Tridion but Visual Studio says I am missing an assembly reference.

I searched for namespace and it requires Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement DLL. Where can I find this DLL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `Fields` property on CoreService. If you see it - you probably have mixed references to TOM.NET and CoreService. You need only reference to CoreService client dll and nothing more. If you wan't to have something similar to Fields implementation - you may take a look at this article: http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata

Comment: Indeed. You should never need to link to Tridion.ContentManager.Data anyway, as it is an internal API.

Comment: @Aquarius24 There's no `Fields` functioanlity in CoreService and you can't fake it with referencing TOM.NET dlls

Comment: @Aquarius24: if you tried that code and it gives problems, you are doing something wrong. Please post your code in the question, so that we can  see what you've actually done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the `Tridion.ContentManagement.Data.DLL` just do this:

- Open cmd from Run
- Navigate to `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Tridion.ContentManager.Data\6.1.0.996__ddfc895746e5ee6b>`
- Copy the file to a folder you want

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for proper layout :-) It hopefully encourage me to provide more to stackoverflow